Show that the minimal polynomial of a linear operator is same as the minimal polynomial of its matrix representation wrt any ordered basis.
Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V,$ and let $β$ be an ordered basis for $V.$ Then the minimal polynomial of $T$ is the same as the minimal polynomial of $[T]_β.$
I tried solving this problem by assuming that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are the minimal polynomials for $T$ and $[T]_β$ respectively. Now, I know that $f(T)=T_0$ and $g(A)=O.$ Also, I proved that $[f(T)]_{\beta}=O\iff f(T)=T_0.$
But I have no idea how to show that $f=g.$ Any help regarding this apparent issue will be highly appreciated.

The minimal polynomial of $T$ is the unique monic polynomial $f$ of minimum degree in the set ${f(x) \in \Bbb{F}[x] : f(T) = 0}$. This definition applies to matrices as well. You just want to show that ${f(x) \in \Bbb{F}[x] : f(T) = 0} = {f(x) \in \Bbb{F}[x] : f([T]\beta) = 0}$. To prove this, you may want to prove that, for any $f(x) \in \Bbb{F}[x]$, $[f(T)]\beta = f([T]_\beta)$ (hint: show it's true when $f(x)$ is a monomial, by induction, then use linearity).

@TheoBendit Thanks for trying to help me, but could you be a little more elaborate please? I am looking for a rigorous proof.

I could... but I'm also trying to just point you in the right direction, leaving some of the details for you to work out for yourself. Are you able to show that $[f(T)]\beta = f([T]\beta)$ as a first step?

@TheoBendit Yes. Moreover, I was able to show that that for a polynomial $f(x)\in P(F)$ we have, $f(T)=T_0\iff f([T]_{\beta})=O$, where $O$ is the zero matrix.

I'm guessing $T_0$ is the zero operator, right? That's good. Then, you know that the two sets I mentioned, ${f(x) \in \Bbb{F}[x] : f(T) = T_0}$ and ${f(x) \in \Bbb{F}[x] : f([T]\beta) = O}$ are the same set. Thus, they have the same minimum degree monic polynomial contained therein -- that is, $T$ and $[T]\beta$ have the same minimal polynomial.
